# For which polynomials $p(x)$ with $deg(p)=3$ has $\sqrt{p(x)}$ an elementary antiderivate?

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form, elementary-functions

> Can the polynomials $p(x)$ with $deg(p)=3$, for which $\sqrt{p(x)}$ has an elementary antiderivate, be somehow classified ?

According to Wolfram alpha, already for $$p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$ , no elementary antiderivate exists, whereas the cases $$p(x)=(x-a)^3$$ and $$p(x)=(x-a)^2(x-b)$$ lead to an elementary antiderivate. However, those cases are very special because of $\sqrt{(x-a)^2}=|x-a|$.

Are those special cases the only cases, or can an elementary antiderivate exist for other $p(x)$ ?

Comment: If $p(x)$ has no repeated roots the antiderivative is an elliptic integral (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), you list the cases **with** repeated roots.

Comment: @gammatester Does that mean that ONLY for such polynomials , an elementary antiderivate exists ?

Comment: IMO yes, because in your case $R(x,y)=y$ contains **only** odd powers of $y$. There is the statement: *Exceptions to this general rule are when P has repeated roots, or when R(x,y) contains no odd powers of y.* But admittedly I am no specialist for this.